# Filtering order for SQL joins on large tables with text

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have multiple large tables (several million rows) of data that need to all be combined via inner joins in a single query and filtered. These tables are all large and some of them contain large text columns. However, I don't need all the large text columns in the result of my query. I could filter the tables incrementally as I join them in subqueries or I could skip the subqueries and just join all the tables and filter in the select clause. Which one of these would be faster, and why?

Example with filtering subquery:

```
select aa.col1, aa.col2, aa.col3, aa.col4, c.col5, c.col6 
from 
(select a.col1, a.col2, b.col3, b.col4 
from table_a a 
join table_b b using(col1)
where a.col2 < 10 and b.col3 > 3) 
as aa
join table_c c using(col1)
```

Example without subquery:

```
select a.col1, a.col2, b.col3, b.col4, c.col5, c.col6
from table_a a 
join table_b b using(col1)
join table_c c using(col1)
where a.col2 < 10 and b.col3 > 3
```

I've done a little bit of research and some people are saying that the filtering order doesn't matter and that the sql query optimizer will choose the most efficient route. However, I've also seen some answers saying to filter incrementally.

With my own experiments in MYSQL, I've found that using subqueries speeds things up due to the large text field. The fetch time dominates the sql execution time (I guess due to large text fields) and filtering the data  before the second join cuts down on the fetch time considerably. However, I don't understand the underlying mechanism for this and don't know if it's a fluke of my particular setup or generally applicable. Are there general rules for this type of query in SQL? Is there a difference between these types of queries in Microsoft SQL Server vs MYSQL? I primarily care about the speed of the entire query.

Answer (score 0):

As per my study the second query is faster. Because subquery takes time. 
Suppose you have a query:

SELECT * FROM table where id IN (SELECT id FROM table where condition1 AND condition 2 )

In this query first the subquery will execute, after selecting the subquery it checks the outer where conditions and then select.

And if you are using joins then it is faster because first it join table on the common field and then it check the other condition and then selects  the data. So they are faster.

Comment: What could be the cause of the first example with subqueries executing faster on my machine than the second example? I'm using MYSQL Workbench and it breaks the queries down into Duration time and Fetch time. 

The first query has (Duration, Fetch) ~= (3 sec, 15 sec), while the second query has (Duration, Fetch) ~= (1.5 sec, 60 sec)


So the Duration is shorter without subqueries, but the Fetch is so much longer that the version with subqueries ends up completing much faster

Comment: you need to specify the join such as left , right or inner , if we talk left join. i have heard that it is faster then subquery. i don't know what you require in your query. But i think if you specify the join. then you get improvement in speed.

Comment: They are all inner joins

Answer (score 0):

Filtering in derived tables can indeed be faster, but... it will depend specifically on the database design, the number of records filtered out, the indexes and other local conditions.  So it is best to write both queries and do performance testing with your own system.  Look at the explain plan for both and test the actual timing for both (you may need to clear the cache bewtteeen for a fair test)